# Adding newly created image object to window

Tags: c#, wpf, object

```
Image myImage3 = new Image();
BitmapImage bi3 = new BitmapImage();
bi3.BeginInit();
bi3.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Awesomeness\PicProgram\Program\bin\Debug\flower.png", UriKind.Relative);
bi3.EndInit();
myImage3.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
myImage3.Source = bi3;
```

I was wondering how I get myImage3 added to the window.

I've tried `this.content.add.myImage3` or `this.add(myImage3)` and other variations none seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: @_the_Down-voter: Try giving feedback as to why you down-voted or newer users won't know how they need to improve their questions.

Comment: are you trying to add this image to a particular control or the form background?  Be a bit more specific as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Josh I am trying to create an image control in the c# and then add it to the WPF window. I dont want it to take up the entire page like a background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a basic wpf usage question, although doing something that is simple in xaml can get a bit complex in code behind.....

You have to add your image to some panel or content control in your window, not the window itself. So if there is a grid in your window, give the grid a name like m_grid, then do m_grid.children.add(myImage3).